# I can't make email signature responsive (folding)

Tags: html, responsive-design

I've tried the code below to fold on smaller screens and cut signature in half using `float:left` command on each of  but it doesn't work. I need to make this footer as it is on larger screens and fold in half on smaller ones :/

```html
<table style="width: 450px;" width="450" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody style="vertical-align: top; position: fixed;">
<br></br>
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-bottom-color: #b50015; vertical-align: bottom; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: #3b4908; padding: 0 0 10px 0;" valign="bottom"><strong><span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 14pt; color: #b50015;">Natalia&nbsp;Gułaś</span></strong><br /><span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #444444;"><span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: #2c2c2c;">Dyrektor Zarządzający</span></span></td>
<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-bottom-color: #b50015; vertical-align: top; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: #3b4908; padding: 0 0 10px 0;" valign="top"><a href="http://gimmik.net/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img style="width: 179px; height: auto; border: 0;" src="https://lp.gimmik.net/upload/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" width="179" border="0" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 60%; line-height: 18px; vertical-align: top; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #444444; padding: 10px 0 0 0;" valign="top" width="60%"><span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #2c2c2c;"><strong><a href="tel:+48882143502" style="text-decoration:none; color: #b50015;">tel.:</a></strong> +48 882 143 502<span><br /></span></span> <span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #2c2c2c;"><strong> <a href="mailto:natalia@gimmik.net" style="text-decoration:none; color: #b50015;" target="_blank" rel="noopener">email:</a></strong> natalia@gimmik.net </span></td>
<td style="width: 40%; line-height: 18px; vertical-align: top; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #444444; padding: 10px 0 0 0;" valign="top" width="40%"><span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #2c2c2c;">Gimmik.net<span><br /></span></span> <span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #2c2c2c;">ul. Mełgiewska 9E<span><br /></span></span> <span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #2c2c2c;">20-209 Lublin</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 60%; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px 0 0 0;" valign="top" width="60%"><span><a href="https://www.facebook.com/wwwgimmikpl/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 1px; border: 0; width: 16px; height: 16px;" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator/plaintext3-with-logo/fb.png" alt="facebook icon" width="16" border="0" /></a>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/gimmikpl" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 1px; border: 0; width: 16px; height: 16px;" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator/plaintext3-with-logo/yt.png" alt="youtube icon" width="16" border="0" /></a>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://www.instagram.com/gimmik_net/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 1px; border: 0; width: 16px; height: 16px;" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator/plaintext3-with-logo/it.png" alt="instagram icon" width="16" border="0" /></a>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td style="width: 40%; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px 0 0 0;" valign="top" width="40%"><span><strong><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.gimmik.net" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #3b4908;"><span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: #b50015;">www.gimmik.net</span></span></a></strong></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you include an image of the desired result on small screens? Should both sides of the top half stack, followed by the horizontal line, followed by both sides of the bottom half stacked?

Comment: I mean, effect that I need to achieve is; if not enough space, table should break in half.

Comment: So the left half on top of the right half? with two horizontal lines through the top quarter and bottom quarter?

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you need to create two separate tables—one for each side—and float them both. You'll also need to hard-set heights on some cells to keep things aligned.

```html
<table width="225" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 58px; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-bottom-color: #b50015; vertical-align: bottom; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: #3b4908; padding: 0 0 10px 0;" valign="bottom"><strong><span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 14pt; color: #b50015;">Natalia&nbsp;Gułaś</span></strong><br /><span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #444444;"><span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: #2c2c2c;">Dyrektor Zarządzający</span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 54px; line-height: 18px; vertical-align: top; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #444444; padding: 10px 0 0 0;" valign="top" width="60%"><span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #2c2c2c;"><strong><a href="tel:+48882143502" style="text-decoration:none; color: #b50015;">tel.:</a></strong> +48 882 143 502<span><br /></span></span> <span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #2c2c2c;"><strong> <a href="mailto:natalia@gimmik.net" style="text-decoration:none; color: #b50015;" target="_blank" rel="noopener">email:</a></strong> natalia@gimmik.net </span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style=" vertical-align: top; padding: 10px 0 0 0;" valign="top" width="60%"><span><a href="https://www.facebook.com/wwwgimmikpl/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 1px; border: 0; width: 16px; height: 16px;" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator/plaintext3-with-logo/fb.png" alt="facebook icon" width="16" border="0" /></a>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/gimmikpl" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 1px; border: 0; width: 16px; height: 16px;" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator/plaintext3-with-logo/yt.png" alt="youtube icon" width="16" border="0" /></a>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://www.instagram.com/gimmik_net/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 1px; border: 0; width: 16px; height: 16px;" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator/plaintext3-with-logo/it.png" alt="instagram icon" width="16" border="0" /></a>&nbsp;</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="225" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 58px; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-bottom-color: #b50015; vertical-align: top; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: #3b4908; padding: 0 0 10px 0;" valign="top"> <a href="http://gimmik.net/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img style="width: 179px; height: auto; border: 0;" src="https://lp.gimmik.net/upload/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" width="179" border="0" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 54px; line-height: 18px; vertical-align: top; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #444444; padding: 10px 0 0 0;" valign="top"><span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #2c2c2c;">Gimmik.net<span><br /></span></span> <span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #2c2c2c;">ul. Mełgiewska 9E<span><br /></span></span> <span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #2c2c2c;">20-209 Lublin</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 10px 0 0 0;" valign="top"><span><strong><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.gimmik.net" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #3b4908;"><span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: #b50015;">www.gimmik.net</span></span></a></strong></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: After copying code to VSC parts of signature doesnt line and mail is lined below :(

Comment: @mpolniak you probably need to clear the floats above and below the tables